# How to fix Python Gekko equation error "SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression"?

Tags: python, solver, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I have an error in a Python Gekko program that says there is a problem with an equation. I know that there are two solutions to this problem where the unit circle intersects the line.

[image]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var()
y = m.Var()
m.Equation(x**2+y**2=1)
m.Equation(x=y)
m.solve()
```

When I put the equations together, it gives a different error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var()
y = m.Var()
m.Equations([x**2+y**2=1,x=y])
m.solve()
```

I can get a solution by including the equations as an objective function but the solver IPOPT reports `x=0, y=0` if I give that initial guess. When I guess `x=1, y=1` it gives one of the correct solutions as `x=0.707, y=0.707`. I would like to have the solver enforce those as hard (not soft) constraints.

```py
m.Obj((x**2+y**2-1)**2)
m.Obj((x-y)**2)
```

What can I do to solve this problem with Python Gekko?

Comment: Surely you want to use `==` everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` in your equations as David mentioned.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var()
y = m.Var()
m.Equation(x**2+y**2==1)
m.Equation(x==y)
m.solve()
```

A common error when writing equations is to use a single equal sign (=) instead of a double equal sign (==). The (=) assigns the quantity on the right to the variable on the left. The (==) is a comparison operator and is used in Gekko to build equality constraints. You can also use other operators such as (<=), (<), (>), and (>=). The not equal to (!=) is not supported in Gekko.

One other thing to consider for your problem is that you are starting from `x=0` and `y=0` when you don't give a starting guess with `x=m.Var()` and `y=m.Var()`. You can find one solution or the other by starting closer to the solution such as `x=m.Var(1)` and `y=m.Var(1)` or add constraints to limit the search space as `x=m.Var(lb=0)` and `y=m.Var(lb=0)`.